# Static files not loaded into templates

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am new to Django and so far all I know about static files is that they are CSS, JS, and images and they should be in a directory called static within the app directory

but when I use one of these files in my template like that:

first I load the static files

```
{% load static %} <!-- in the 1st line of the template -->
```

then I link the CSS file like that

```
<link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

They don't load and the styles don't seem to appear
so I just want to know what I am missing here

this is the project tree [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUsCw.png)

static root and url from settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'E:/Work/SoftwareDevelopment/Web/Django/commerce/auctions/static'
```

Comment: Kindly add more details, where 'auctions/styles.css' exist? related setting to static files? ..etc...

Comment: I added the project tree and static settings to the question

Answer (score 1):

Did you ran `python manage.py collectstatic`?

You also need to configurate your settings.py with `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Comment: According to the docs the "runserver" command serves the static files automatically as long as DEBUG = True and I will need the "collectstatic" command only on deployment
and the STATIC_URL = '/static/' is done automatically on creating the project 
yet I made sure it's set to '/static/' and updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Are your auctions's static folder separated in css, js, images folders? If so, you are missing specifying that in static:

`'auctions/css/styles.css'`

If that doesn't work, try running collectstatic manually and getting the path to the file from there to pass in the html.